# Unable to find explicit activity class error

Tags: android

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exampl.fitindya"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
              android:label="Register New Account"></activity>
</application>
```

Don't know why this error is appearing and application crashes. please help guys.can there be any problem anywhere else

here is my class file

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button login_b1;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: show your MainActivity.Class file

Comment: @MohitPal I guess you have to specify  the intent Filter for ur register Activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code below the register Activity. I **guess** that should be the error

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```